# hyperref and index not working

Tags: hyperref, indexing, makeindex

A click on an index entry ends always on the first page of the book

```
\documentclass[envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
...
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered, hyperindex, pageanchor]{hyperref}
```

entries in *.ind  list the page number

```
\item $G_0$\idxquad \hyperpage{96}
\item $G_1$\idxquad \hyperpage{96}
```

message in *.log  (pdflatex logfile)

> pdfTeX warning (dest): name{page.167} has been referenced but does not exist, r
>   eplaced by a fixed one
>
> pdfTeX warning (dest): name{page.73} has been referenced but does not exist, re
>   placed by a fixed one

etc.

Comment: Make a *complete* example that can be tested.

Comment: It looks like undefined/mixed up references. Make sure you run all tools in the right sequence the right number of times. Or go for something like latexmk.

Comment: I use svmono of Springer Verlag and the problem is the macro \chapter{Chapter 1}, if included the index looses its memory, \section{Section 1} does not have this effect. Inside the chapters and across chapters hyperref works as expected.

Comment: Problem solved: The culprit was \usepackage{cropmark}. When I excluded this package everything works as it should. Thanks to U. Fischer for the tip do study the problem with a small test file.